# facebook javaScript sdk event invited not working properly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the invited to an event via javaScript. I've already done the log in, and I have the access to the event, but I have a problem when I request the people invited. I do get a result, but length of the invited array is always 25 and should be more. I noticed that I get only people who haves the 
rsvp_status = "attending"

```
FB.api(
            "/"+id+"/invited",
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    $scope.attending = response.data;
                    $scope.$digest();
                }
            }
      );
```

The count of the people invited to the event should be 103 and the participants 51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

25 is the standard limit of results returned from the Graph API. You either have to implement paging (that is the preferred way, via the `paging` object's `next` property), or increase the limit of results via the `limit` parameter.

Note that the `limit` can't be set to a very large number (like 10000), because the Graph API will truncete the results. AFAIK there's no documented maximum size.

```
 FB.api(
        "/"+id+"/invited?limit=200",
        function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                $scope.attending = response.data;
                $scope.$digest();
            }
        }
  );
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

Comment: Perfect, thank you, with the limit parameter worked properly